# Extract all occurrences with regexp_substr

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I try to extract all objects (view or tables) that are used as sources in the view code (SQL in `dbc.tableV.requestText`), but I failed to do that.

I use `regexp_substr`, but I can extract only one occurrence and not all occurrences.

Do you know if it is possible to extract all occurrences in Teradata with `regexp_substr`? Or do you have another method to extract view and tables from a request?

What I have done so far:

```
select 
    /* Replace new ligne by space, convert to CLOB to avoid restriction limit for regexp_replace*/
    cast( regexp_replace( cast(RequestText as CLOB) , '\n|\r',' '   )  as  varchar(18000) ) as Texte_Sans_Saut_Ligne

    /* Replace multi-space by one space, convert to CLOB to avoid restriction limit for regexp_replace*/*/
    ,UPPER(cast( regexp_replace( cast(Texte_Sans_Saut_Ligne as CLOB) , '[ ]{2,}',' '    )  as  varchar(12500) )) as Texte_Suppr_Espace
    
    /* delete function who use FROM (ex: EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date) => on identifie l'ensemble des chaine de caractéres qui commence par '(' et finisse par ')' (arret au premier ")" via ?), on exclue juste les cas ou ça commence par SELECT ou multiple espace SELECT) */
    ,cast( regexp_replace( cast(Texte_Suppr_Espace as CLOB) , '\((?! *SELECT).*?\)',''  )  as  varchar(12500) ) as Texte_Suppr_Fct_From

    /* extract datasource for old fashion way to do join ( from table1 , table2) */
    /* /!\ ISSUES : can only extract one occurence of datasource */
    ,regexp_substr(Texte_Suppr_Fct_From,'FROM ( *\w*\.\w* *\w* *,* *)*(WHERE|;)',1,1) as Extract_From_Virg
    
    /* extract datasource for JOIN or FROM (from table1 inner JOIN table2 or ) */
    ,regexp_substr(Texte_Suppr_Fct_From,'(FROM|JOIN) \w*\.\w*',1,2) as Extract_From_JOIN

From DBC.tablesV
```

P.S.: My regexp aren't perfect; if a work around is found, I think more work will need to be done.

Comment: I don't think you are going to simply parse SQL using regexes. Not to mention, tablesV doesn't always have the full query, as explained in a response to your last post.

Comment: I agree but I don't search to parse all types of  SQL code, only datasource for view. And I think it is possible.